# how add link in option value on chosen js

Tags: javascript, html

good hi, i am using Chosen js https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/ 
but I need to call a function when you do not find any value in the list
that's my code:

i have this :

```
<select name="cboTipoProducto" id="cboTipoProducto" class="chzn-select"   <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>

<script type="text/javascript">$(function(){

$(".chzn-select").chosen({no_results_text: "<a href='myfunction' >"}); });
```

but not working  please help me . thanks

Comment: hello, can you provide us with more code so we can see where the error occurs?

Comment: add the selected attribute